# Why I get this error in flutter? Constructor error?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to add some icons to my Flutter code. When I try to add them I get this error message. "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments."
Can someone here tell me what can I do to fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:color/color.dart';


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 32,
            vertical: 16.0,
          )),
          Container(
         color: Colors.grey[900],         
         child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              //height: 150,
             // width: 150,
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
            ),
             Spacer(),
         Text("Escorts",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Angenturen & Clubs",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Inserieren",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Werben",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Blog",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         SizedBox(width: 32,),
         Text("Kontakt",
         style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white , fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
         Spacer(
         Icon(Icons.heart_broken)
         )
          ],
         ),
          ),
        
          
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to add them to the navbar. It's in the end of the code. @Gwhyyy

Comment: Try to add directly, not inside of spacer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the `Icon` inside the `Spacer`. You can't put anything inside a spacer. Maybe you meant to put it after it? So instead of

```
Spacer(
  Icon(Icons.heart_broken)
)
```

do

```
Spacer(),
Icon(Icons.heart_broken)
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `spacer` as parent of `icon`, which is wrong. change it to this:

```
Stack(
  children: [
   ...
   Spacer(),
   Icon(Icons.heart_broken),
  ],
)
```